# Add click event handler for objects in PowerPoint Online slides

Tags: office365, office-js

I have a requirement to handle clicks on elements in PowerPoint Online slides without affecting the design or behavior of the same slide viewed offline.

To show a custom navigation overlay, we're already using a simple wrapper page to host a full-page embedded iframe PowerPoint viewer.  One idea is to insert `javascript:` hyperlinks into the slide to call a known function in the host page or use postMessage.  However, hyperlinks can only be created on text, and they introduce visual design changes (color and underline).  So a solution that doesn't require hyperlinks is preferable.

Is there a way to associate custom data to PowerPoint objects, and then attach event handlers to communicate that custom data up to our host page?